# How to download table from a website using wget/curl?

Tags: command-line, wget, curl

http://www.dgda.gov.bd/index.php/manufacturers/allopathic

I want to download the table from this site.

Comment: This site is not open [Time Out ] !

Comment: The site generates the table using JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554113/how-to-get-webcontent-that-is-loaded-by-javascript-using-curl

Answer (score 3):

This will download the json data that fill the table:

```
curl --data "action=getDrugCompanyDatabaseData" http://www.dgda.gov.bd/administrator/components/com_jcode/source/serverProcessing.php
```

Or save it to a file

```
curl --data "action=getDrugCompanyDatabaseData" http://www.dgda.gov.bd/administrator/components/com_jcode/source/serverProcessing.php > output.json
```

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro B. If you will explain that how to find/generate this link http://www.dgda.gov.bd/administrator/components/com_jcode/source/serverProcessing.php > output.json it is easy for me for another downloading like from http://www.dgda.gov.bd/index.php/manufacturers/ayurvedic

Comment: I have found the link "sAjaxSource": SiteURL + "administrator/components/com_jcode/source/serverProcessing.php",
 "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']], for http://www.dgda.gov.bd/index.php/manufacturers/allopathic and "sAjaxSource": SiteURL + "administrator/components/com_jcode/source/serverProcessing.php",
  "aaSorting": [
   [2, 'asc'] for http://www.dgda.gov.bd/index.php/manufacturers/ayurvedic. But from your answer I can't distinguish these.

Comment: Can anybody explain the answer? it will be helpful for another.