# How to extract data from web site through wget or curl

Tags: php, wget, extract

I need to extract the result of the table dinamically generated in this website: http://reportaziende.it/cercaAvanzata.php

I found this topic: 
[How to download table from a website using wget/curl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867023/how-to-download-table-from-a-website-using-wget-curl)

but I just cannot adapt it to my need, would you please help me?

thanks

Comment: Please edit to include your failed attempt to implement the sourced solution and complete your question.  If you managed to resolve this in the last 3 years, you can post an answer then accept it to mark this page as resolved.  Please never abandon Stack Exchange questions.